# what is diffrent between WSGIRequest and django HttpRequest?

Tags: python, django

in django view ,I check the type of request :
it shows <class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>

```
def simpleview(request):
    print(type(request))
```

output:
<class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>

but in  [django documenttion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/) but django has documented HttpRequest
what is the diffrent beetween these two ?

Answer (score 5):

Not an awful lot.

One is a base class for all HTTP requests, one is specific for the WSGI protocol that application servers use to talk with Django, and it derives from HttpRequest.